# Load text file into mysql database and add timestamp to each row

Tags: php, mysql, csv, datetime, load-data-infile

I have a text file that has serial numbers on each line such as:

```
7656393835734594
8457457435983945
3489534689856950
4596859684560498
```

I want to add this text file into a mysql table using PHP. My table looks like this:

```
serials table
    id           bigint(20) auto_increment
    serial       varchar(16)    
    timestamp    timestamp
```

How can I add each line from the text file into the serial column and also add the current timestamp to each row?

Here is what I have already tried:

```
$file = "serials.txt";
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysqli_select_db($conn, 'myDB');
mysqli_query($conn, "LOAD DATA INFILE '".$file."' INTO TABLE serials");
```

This code does not do anything let alone add the data and the timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the simplest approach is to define a `default` value for the `timestamp` column:

```
create table serials (
    id bigint primary key auto_increment,
    serial varchar(16),
    ts timestamp default current_timestamp
)
```

Note that I renamed to timestamp column to some name that does not conflict with a language keyword.

You can then use the `load data` syntax. An important thing is that you need to provide a column list, since not all table columns are given for insert:

```
load data infile 'myfile.txt' into table serials(serial)
```

On the other hand, if you can't modify the table definition for some reason, an alternative is to use the `set` clause to provide the derived value:

```
load data infile 'myfile.txt' into table serials(serial)
set ts = current_timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

if the file is local to the connection script, it should be `LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL` and before the connection:

```
mysqli_options($conn, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
```

Check the server settings has:

```
local_infile=ON
```

Alternately if you want the server to load the file [secure_file_priv](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) needs to be the path where the file is.